# Unable to access child structural directive from parent structural directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-di

I am trying to access child structural directive from parent directive.

This is how I'm trying to access the child

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appChildStruralDirective]'
})
export class ChildStruralDirective {
  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[appParentStruralDirective]'
})
export class ParentStruralDirective {
  @ViewChild(ChildStruralDirective) viewChild: ChildStruralDirective;
  @ContentChild(ChildStruralDirective) contentChild: ChildStruralDirective;

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit:viewChild', this.viewChild);
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit:contentChild', this.contentChild);
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
    console.log('ngAfterContentChecked:viewChild', this.viewChild);
    console.log('ngAfterContentChecked:contentChild', this.contentChild);
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <h1 *appParentStruralDirective>
     <span *appChildStruralDirective>Hello world</span>
   </h1>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why the child directive is not accessible.

I have created a plunkr to demonstrate the issue.

https://plnkr.co/edit/deQC6cY4oHuNdKbzsfhE?p=preview

Please let me know why this is not working.

PS: I have used both ViewChild & ContentChild (most likely candidate) as I'm not sure which one this will fall into as these are dynamically generated elements.

Comment: You can inject a service to register the child structural directive on the service.

Comment: That defeats the purpose of having DI

Comment: AFAIK it won't work. Create issue on github https://github.com/angular/angular/issues

Comment: Created an issue. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16840

Comment: You cannot inject `ParentStruralDirective` because it is not part of DI tree. You can inject only components

Comment: what do u mean defeat ? this is what exactly angular DI is about you can say providers:[MyService] on the not structural directive and after that inject the service in the constructor of each structural directive.

Comment: You are working around the problem. The directives are part of the view & the children of the parent directive are created by `this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);`. So, these should be accessible to the parent the same way viewchild & contentchild are accessible from component

Comment: @yurzui I can access parent from child, but not the other way around

Comment: `I can access parent from child` Can you reproduce it here?https://plnkr.co/edit/h8WWtcOAViMudBYjdEOZ?p=preview

Comment: View Engine was introduced. I think that it worked before Angular 4 was an unintended side effect.

Comment: It seems to be working only in 2.4.0, but not in 4.1.2, not sure why. Here is the repo where it does work.

https://github.com/thekalinga/angular-structural-directive-test

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/N2sS0uOvlNw6Czbjb3ze?p=preview

Oddly in plunkr, the parent is being mapped to `window`, but in the actual cli project, it returns the correct parent

Comment: Again, these are working only 2.4.0, but not in 4.1.2 (the latest version)

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova Also, if you have multiple instances of parent & child within the same template/across templates, linking a given parent to a given child(ren) requires using individual unique keys (potentially unique across the application) to be shared between each parent & children combination if we use service approach

Comment: each parent-child will get its own instance of service if u inject it into component - this is a beauty of Angular 2 DI.

Comment: i will try to answer and create a plunker

Comment: Updated my comment above.

Creating one service for each combination of parent & child to get around the core DI job angular should be doing, will have a performance hit + doesn't seems to be a good idea. 

Like I said earlier, you are working around core issue of DI.

Comment: Since Angular already knows the directive that created a child(ren) directive, he should allow us to access the child with almost zero performance hit.

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova Please do share your approach as it might help me & others, incase if Angular itself does not allow that as of now. Thanks for your suggestions. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a service for each combination Parent-Child.

Here is plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/zNf7iZtOQtlsSfYOfq5D?p=preview

```
  @Injectable()
  export class MyState{
    id;
    child;
  }

  @Directive({
    selector: '[appChildStruralDirective]'
  })
  export class ChildStruralDirective {
    random;

    constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private myState : MyState) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
     this.myState.child = this;
     this.random = Math.random();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    }
  }

  @Directive({
    selector: '[appParentStruralDirective]'
  })
  export class ParentStruralDirective {
    child;

    constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private renderer: Renderer,
    private s : MyState) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    }
  }

  @Component({
    selector: 'my-comp',
    providers: [MyState],
    template: `
    <fieldset style="margin-top:50px">
       <button (click)="showMyState()">Show My State</button>
       <h1 *appParentStruralDirective>
         <span *appChildStruralDirective>Hello world {{id}}</span>
       </h1>
     </fieldset>
    `,
  })
  export class MyCmp {
    @Input() id: string;
    constructor(private myState: MyState) {
    }

    ngOnInit(){
      this.myState.id=this.id;
    }

    showMyState() {
      console.log(this.myState);
    }
  }

  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <my-comp [id]="'one'"></my-comp>
        <my-comp [id]="'two'"></my-comp>
    `,
  })
  export class App {
    constructor() {
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the plunkr.

Its the same thing I refering to when I said we need to have multiple unique keys per service that refers to each instance of parent & child combo if I were to have multiple instances of `appParentStruralDirective` within the above component's template. (which so happens to be my requirement)

However, this should serve as the first step before a native angular solution is available.

I need to allow individual read only fields editable inline on an arbitrary component. Along the lines of something similar to JIRA https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11731